BigQuery external table error while running queries
I have created a BigQuery external table. It refers to a GCP bucket where I have csv files containing e-commerce product details. There are close to 1.5 million files; each file contains a single product detail in the form
<product_id>, <product_json>.
When I try to run a simple query, for example:
SELECT * FROM <external-table> WHERE product_id='0RCN5Z1Y9J64';
I get the error
Not found: Files gs:///product_json/0V9QAEFA5VN0.csv (Version 1714969112548075)
What could be the possible reason? Each time, the file and version are different. Please note that data is constantly being added or files are getting overwritten while I run the query.
 

What does your table definition look like that is pointing to the GCS bucket?  What is going through my mind is that processing may be being performed in two passes .. 1 generates a list of CSV files to examine and the next examines their content.  If you are working on a dynamically changing bucket, might a file object be "gone" between when the listing of files to be processed is performed and when the files is to be examined?
